# ValidateAntiForgeryToken presenving cookie value for the session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am not sure whether this is a "feature" or a bug on the MVC framework.

While implementing a few actions with the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attribute on them I've noticed that although on the view, the **_*RequestVerificationToken*** hidden text field changes with every re-load of the page, the cookie **_RequestVerificationToken_Lw__** always remains the same for the length of the session, i.e. all views will use the same cookie value to compare against.

From what I can gather, the value on the view is different because it gets encrypted every time but in reality, like the cookie, it's also the same as the cookie for the length of the session.

My question is. Shouldn't we be able to force this cookie to have a different value for every different request?

I would have thought that keeping the same cookie value for the length of the session is a security risk, as a malicious hacker could get hold of it and our CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) preventive measures would go out of the window.

Is there a way of forcing this cookie to get a different value for each request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cookie is still part of a three pronged protection.

They must have

1. The cookie
2. Your login name (hence your forms auth cookie)
3. The anti forgery token from the page.

With that in mind and using ssl (which you should always be using!) given the fact the tokens are NOT one time use tokens anyways, your protection level would likely not change.

Comment: I am using ssl and my cookies are all set to secure=true but I find it concerning that as I mentioned above, if a malicious hacker gets hold of my cookie, all my preventive measures to stop CSRF attacks are rendered completely useless. I think that having a different cookie value per request would make it more secure, even if it's a different cookie every time.

Comment: no, they arent (rendered useless just by having the cookie). They still need to be logged on as you (which means stealing that cookie too if using forms auth) and they also need your form token as well. If they get a hold of your cookie which is an http only cookie then they likely sniffed the session in which case would have your form token as well. IE if they get one they likely have the other. Your form tokens that change with each request are not one time use tokens. They can be replayed as well unfortunately.